# How to deal with deleted-because-downvoted answers; written up as NEW afterwards?

Tags: discussion, answers, deleted-answers

Just came across this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36460045/simple-selection-sort-in-python); more specially: the fact that there was a late answer (which looks actually correct to me). That late answer was downvoted, and the originator ... deleted it; and put up the same content in a new answer.

Now I am wondering: what is the correct way to address that? I did look around, but did not find a question here; or guideline elsewhere.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Flag for a moderator, we'll delete the duplicate and restore the original, and potentially message the user asking them to stop where there is evidence of repeat offenses.